# OAuth2 Single Log Out using python flask

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid-connect

I'm trying to implement OAuth SLO using google IDP. This is just a test application. I couldn't find any proper way to implement SLO in my application. Can Someone suggest me the best way to implement SLO, which supports all the IDP in the market.

I tried couple of methods, but doesn't seems to work as expected.

1. I tried to clear the session and revoke the access token, its not working.
2. I tried to redirect to the google's logout url `https://accounts.google.com/logout`

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, request, session
import requests
import json
import secrets
import hashlib
import base64


app = Flask(__name__)
secret = secrets.token_hex(16)
app.secret_key = secret
authorization_endpoint = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth'
client_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'
client_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx'
redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:5000/response'
scope = 'profile email'
token_endpoint = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'

temp_access_token = ''

# PKCE settings
code_verifier = secrets.token_urlsafe(64)
code_challenge = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(hashlib.sha256(code_verifier.encode()).digest()).decode().rstrip('=')

@app.route('/authorize')
def authorize():
    global auth_url
    auth_url = authorization_endpoint + '?response_type=code' + '&client_id=' + client_id + '&redirect_uri=' + redirect_uri + '&scope=' + scope 
    print("auth_url", auth_url)
    print("**********", redirect(auth_url))
    return redirect(auth_url)


@app.route('/response')
def login():
    global temp_access_token
    print("authorization_code", request.args)
    authorization_code = request.args.get('code')

    token_request_body = {
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'code': authorization_code,
        'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
        'scope': scope,
        # 'scope': scope + ' offline_access',
        'client_id': client_id,
        'client_secret': client_secret
        # 'code_verifier': code_verifier
    }
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
    response1 = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=token_request_body, headers=headers)
    response1_data = json.loads(response1.text)

    access_token = response1_data['access_token']
    session['access_token'] = access_token
    # refresh_token = response1_data['refresh_token']
    
    graph_api_endpoint = 'https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo'
    graph_api_headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
        }
    print("access_token", access_token)
    graph_api_response = requests.get(graph_api_endpoint, headers=graph_api_headers)
    graph_api_response_data = json.loads(graph_api_response.text)
    print(graph_api_response_data)
    return graph_api_response_data


def revoke_token(access_token):
    revoke_url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=' + access_token
    requests.get(revoke_url)


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    # Clear the user's session data
    logout_url = 'https://accounts.google.com/logout'
    requests.session().cookies.clear()
    access_token = session.get('access_token')
    if access_token:
        revoke_token(access_token)
    requests.session().cookies.clear()
    return redirect(auth_url)
    # return redirect(logout_url)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```